# What is expected back pressure at a constant flow rate?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

There is discrepancy between 2 labs regarding what the normal pump back pressure should be given the following dimensions of an LC system flowing at a constant rate.  I have searched for equations to determine this and check if the software read back is correct but I have been unsuccessful at determining an appropriate equation.

System dimensions and set up are as follows:

1. 1.254m of PEEK tubing going from the pump to the MS inlet with a single 2uM PEEK filter attached in-line (no column).
2. The inner diameter of the PEEK tubing is 127 um.
3. Flow rate 1mL/min
4. Solvent = 84% Acetonitrile in water with 0.1% formic acid.

In this instance, assume an open ended system in which the end of the tubing is disconnected from the MS inlet and collected into beaker.

Is there an equation to determine what the pressure should be?

Comment: I think the very small dimensions of your setup require a more specialized treatment than what the Bernoulii equations/normal pipe flow calculations are meant for. But, the discrepancy can be because of small variations in each lab's setup.

Comment: If you want to model the system, you'll probably have to start directly from the Navier-Stokes equations and look at publications on microfluidics to discern how to simplify the solving.

Comment: Thank you.  The discrepancy is several hundred PSI between each system which are 'identical'.  I realize there could be small pressure fluctuations depending on the tightness of the frits.  No leaks have been observed so I was hoping to determine mathematically what one could roughly expect given the dimensions and flow rate.  What 'specialized treatment' do you recommend?

Comment: I meant that you won't be able to use the simpler equations used for pipeflow that is in the inches to feet scale (I think). My second comment is an attempt to layout the specialized work that might be needed; I have no experience with flows at such a small scale so you may want to see if you can reach out to any fluid dynamics specialists.